# Authentification fails with TeamViewer after reinstalling the application

Tags: macos, ssh, teamviewer

I used to control a remote computer via TeamViewer. This morning, my TeamViewer application (I am on Mac OS) crashed while I was using it. It then failed to open and close properly. I did not understand what causes the problem but I trashed my TeamViewer application to install a new one. Now, TeamViewer manage to open but authentification fail when I try to take control of the remote computer. The partner ID and password I am using are correct (at least I am sure I used the same info that were working with my previous TeamViewer application).

**How can I take solve my issue and take control of this computer again?**

---

FYI, I know the IP address of the remote computer. I used to `ssh` to this computer using this IP address and it worked when I was close to this computer but I am now on the other side of the planet and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Restart the team viewer service in remote machine and then try to authenticate

Comment: I don't have access to this machine. There is 5177 km between us and everybody who could access this computer is in holiday! Do you have another solution? :)

Comment: Have you considered that it no longer has internet connection? Or is turned off? If you can't SSH or get on using TV... Do you have access to any other device in the same location to try and ping it internally? Perhaps even RDP if it's online...

Comment: Install team viewer in any other machine in your location and try to connect the machine and if it is successful we can conclude no problem with your machine.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that something like that cause this issue. It would however be quite surprising. I can't really check if this is the issue from where I am. I had this `ssh` issue before already. It is unrelated with my TeamViewer authentification problem. The message I get is `Authentification rejected`. Would I get this message if the remote computer happened to be turned off?

Comment: Yes, I successfully connect to a nearby computer on which I installed TeamViewer. So do I just have to accept that the remote computer of interest is off or is disconnected from internet, or something similar?